# Constructor with lambda expression as parameter of generic type

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, expression

I'd like to create some objects of class Material from different BindingSources.

How can I write a lambda expression so that I don't have to specify type in constructor ?

Example:

```
namespace test1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Wood class defined in other assembly 
            List<Wood> woodList = new List<Wood>();
            woodList.Add(new Wood("Oak", 750));
            woodList.Add(new Wood("Spruce", 450));

        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = woodList;

        //don't want to specify type in code
        Material<Wood> z2 = new Material<Wood>(1, bs, (i) => (Wood)(bs.Current));

            // Can I create object this way with lambda expression ?
            //Material<t> z1 = new Material<t>(1, bs, (lambda expression ??));
    }
}


public class Material<T> where T : class
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    private T _item;
    public Material(
        int _id,
        BindingSource _bindSource,
        Func<object, T> _getTypeParameter)
    {
        this.ID = _id;
        T _item = _getTypeParameter(_bindSource.Current);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can I create object this way with lambda expression ?

Simply: no, you *have* to provide the generic argument when calling a constructor. However you can wrap your constructor-call into a generic factory-method:

```
Material<T> CreateMaterial<T>(int _id, BindingSource _bindSource, Func<object, T> _getTypeParameter)
{
    return new Material<T>(_id, _bindingSource, _getTypeParamer);
}
```

Now the compiler is able to infer the type automatically from the passed arguments:

```
 Material<Wood> z2 = CreateMaterial(1, bs, (i) => (Wood)(bs.Current));
```